# sharepoint sql server connection in Windows Azure does not work

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, azure, active-directory

I am stuck with a connection from a MS SharePoint Server 2013 to an MS SQL Server 2012 in Windows Azure. I built three VMs: An ADDC, An MSSQL Server and the SharePoint Server. All of them are in the same subnet.

When I am trying connect the SQL Server during the SharePoint setup I am getting following error:

> Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at xxx.cloudapp.net. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.

The firewall on the SQL Server is deactivated (for testing), The Domain User is listed in database/security/logins and all rights are granted. Perhaps I am missing something.

Connectionstring:
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=MyDB.cloudapp.net

Comment: Please edit your question to show the connection string (obscure the sensitive parts).

Comment: And... since you're using the public route (via cloudapp.net) instead of connecting directly through your virtual network, did you set up an input endpoint port on your SQL VM?

Comment: I forgot to add the endpoint for 1433. But it did not help. I tested it with the local IP (192.168.128.5) and FQDN. I got the same results. Its the errormessage mentioned above.